# Devise Ominauth won't save email address in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, devise

I had this working but somehow it's now broken.  Banging my head at this for hours... I've watched Ryan Bates video 10x. Everything seems correct.. why can't I get save email address in user model???

I have this in user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :soundcloud]

attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :city, :country


def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_user)
  where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s).first_or_create do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.username = auth.info.name
  user.avatar = auth.info.image
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_secret = auth.credentials.secret
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  auth.provider == "soundcloud" ?  user.save(:validate => false) :  user.save
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

So by simply commenting out the attr_accessor line now I'm able to save all the user data including email address.  Anyone want to chime in on why that works this way?